# Is a string property itself threadsafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

String's in C# are immutable and threadsafe. But what when you have a public getter property? Like this:

```
public String SampleProperty{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

If we have two threads and the first is calling 'get' and the second is calling 'set' at the "same" time, what will happen?

IMHO the set must made a lock to be thread-safe like this:

```
private string sampleField;
private object threadSafer = new object();

public String SampleProperty{
    get{ return this.sampleField; }
    private set{
        lock(threadSafer){
            sampleField = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The "requirement" is: All threads who use (read) the property must have the same / most-up-to-date value. But only the object itself modifies the value.
The keyword 'volatile' should guarantee this, or not?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Most of the answers are using the word "atomic" as if atomic changes are all that are needed. They're not, usually.

This has been mentioned in the comments, but not usually in the answers - that's the only reason for me providing this answer. (The point about locking at a coarser granularity, to allow things like appending, is entirely valid as well.)

Usually you want a reading thread to see the *latest* value of the variable/property. That [isn't guaranteed by atomicity](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml). As a quick example, here's a *bad* way to stop a thread:

```
class BackgroundTaskDemo
{
    private bool stopping = false;

    static void Main()
    {
        BackgroundTaskDemo demo = new BackgroundTaskDemo();
        new Thread(demo.DoWork).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        demo.stopping = true;
    }

    static void DoWork()
    {
         while (!stopping)
         {
               // Do something here
         }
    }
}
```

`DoWork` may well loop forever, despite the write to the boolean variable being atomic - there's nothing to stop the JIT from caching the value of `stopping` in `DoWork`. To fix this, you either need to lock, make the variable `volatile` or use an explicit memory barrier. This all applies to string properties as well.

Comment: Great. That's what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 19):

A reference-type field's get/set (ldfld/stfld) is (IIRC) guaranteed to be atomic, so there shouldn't be any risk of corruption here. So it should be thread-safe from **that** angle, but personally I'd lock the data at a higher level - i.e.

```
lock(someExternalLock) {
    record.Foo = "Bar";
}
```

or maybe:

```
lock(record.SyncLock) {
    record.Foo = "Bar";
}
```

This allows you to make multiple reads/updates to the same **object** as an atomic operation, so that other threads can't get an invalid object-state

Comment: TomTom: As Andreas Huber pointed out in a comment in my answer, the locking you propse happens automatically, however it won't protect you from a point where two threads try to modify the property, whic is why Marc proposes locking the property (the higher level), not the field (lower level).

Comment: (off-topic, but I'd welcome feedback from who-ever donated that downvote; I won't take it personally - if there is an issue in the reply, please let me know)

Comment: Marc: My "requirement" is that all threads which just read the value always have the most-up-to-date value. Only the "origin" object should manipulate the value (therfore the private setter). So the keyword 'volatile' should fit my needs. Hopefully.

Comment: @Marc, you're confusing atomic with visiblity.  All assignments in .Net are atomic but not necessarily immediately visible.  A memory barrier is required for visiblity (lock's have an implicit memory barrier).

Comment: @JaredPar - no, I'm not... and AFAIK, there is no atomic guarantee if you access too much data; so a long is not atomic when using x86, since a long is 64 bits. A reference is, however, guaranteed to be atomic, i.e. you won't see half the old reference and half the new reference (high/low bits).

Comment: @Marc: Jared is right. A 32bit field write operation is indeed atomic but there's no guarantee that the written value is immediately visible to all threads. So given TomTom's requirements, all threads wanting to read or write the value have to use a memory barrier of some sort (lock, volatile, etc.)

Comment: @Marc, true for long.  But in this case we are talking about a reference.

Comment: @JaredPar - yes, which I said was atomic, but that shouldn't be assumed. It is, in fact, atomic - which is very very useful!

Answer (score 4):

Setting the string is an atomic operation, i.e. you will either get the new string or the old string, you'll never get garbage.

If you're doing some work e.g.

```
obj.SampleProperty = "Dear " + firstName + " " + lastName;
```

then string concatination all happens before the call to set, therefore sampleField will always either be the new string or the old.

If however your string concatination code is self referential e.g.

```
obj.SampleProperty += obj.SampleProperty + "a";
```

and else where on another thread you have

```
obj.SampleProperty = "Initial String Value";
```

Then you need the lock.

Consider you're working with an int. If you're assigning to the int, and any value you get from the int is valid, then you don't need to lock it.

However, if the int is keeping count of the number of widgets processed by two or more threads, for the count to be accurate, you need to lock the int.
It's the same situation for strings.

I've a feeling I didn't explain this very well, hope it helps.

Thanks

BW

Comment: Locking at the level the OP has proposed won't protect you from unexpected results with

obj.SampleProperty += "a";

With this operation a lock is taken to get the property, then the lock is released, then a new string is created with "a" appended, then the lock is taken again to set the string.

Comment: Good point, this is true. I suppose this is where Marc Gravells point comes in on locking the assignment to the property, not the assignment to the field. + 1 to Marc (it's seems there's a reason he's on +20k rep)

Answer (score 0):

This is thread-safe without any need for locking. Strings are reference types, so only a reference to the string is being modified. References are of a type are guaranteed to be atomic (Int32 on 32 bit systems and Int64 on 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Your second code sample is definitely not right, because locks only have the desired effect when they are used in *all* places where the variable is accessed (both for get *and* set), so the `get` would also need a lock.

However, when getting and setting a reference-type field as a property like this, then adding a lock statement doesn't add any value. Assignments to pointers are guaranteed to be atomic in the .NET environment, and if multiple threads are changing a property then you have an inherent race condition anyway (where threads may see different values; this may or may not be a problem) so there's little point in locking.

So for what it does, the first piece of code is fine. But whether you really want to build inherent race conditions into a multi-threaded application is another matter.