# Example of 'volatile' preventing a compiler optimization in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, synchronization, volatile

From what I understand, the 'volatile' modifier in C# has two effects:

1. Inserts fences as necessary for the target processor
2. Prevents certain compiler optimizations

On x86 / amd64, (1) is irrelevant. Those processors don't require fences for volatile semantics. (ia64 is different, though.)

So, we are down to (2). But, for examples that I tried, volatile does not make any difference to the jit-ted assembly.

**My question is: Can you give an example of a C# code sample where adding a 'volatile' modifier on a field results in different jit-ted assembly code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133270/how-to-illustrate-usage-of-volatile-keyword-in-c/1284007#1284007) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for! Here, volatile indeed results in different assembly code.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, without a volatile modifier, the field value gets cached in a register. And, when the value is in a register, the looping core will never 'notice' the update done by another core.

Answer (score 1):

Marc Gravell has an [repeatable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458173/can-a-c-thread-really-cache-a-value-and-ignore-changes-to-that-value-on-other-th/458193#458193) of how the lack of a volatile keyword can cause problems.

It's also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222184/do-i-need-to-lock-or-mark-as-volatile-when-accessing-a-simple-boolean-flag-in-c).

It's worth noting (as Marc does) that the compiler optimisations are only seen when compiled in Release mode.