# Benefits of locking a variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I found the below code in our application. As per my understanding of how lock works, I cannot see how this provides any benefit, or that removing this can cause any issues.

```
    private static object _lockTransferInProgress = new object();
    private static volatile bool _transferInProgress = false;
    public static bool Dialer_TransferInProgress
    {
        get { return _transferInProgress; }
        set
        {
            lock (_lockTransferInProgress)
            {
                _transferInProgress = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Does this provide any benefits?
2. Are there risks to removing this?

Comment: You also need to bear in mind that the variable is marked [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

Comment: The lock prevents another thread from entering that code block while another thread is inside it, yes there is a risk in removing it.

Comment: This question is hard to answer without context. There could be very good reason why the person has flagged this volatile and added locking or these reason could be entirely spurious.

Comment: According to the duplicate's answer you need a lock **or** volatile, not both. The `lock` is more expensive so i'd remove it.

Comment: Assignment of a bool variable in .NET is atomic so no need for a lock.

Comment: Though each has a slightly different semantic.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov that's [not what Mark says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1222325/542251)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I don't agree on the the duplicate mark. The duplicate's answer is about **accessing**, this question is about **assignment**. Even if this is probably also discussed somewhere.

Comment: @Liam, That's what Eric [says](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two/). And also should add that you misinterpreted the Marc's answer as he discussed access which non atomic verification `if(_cancelled)` which is absolutely different story.

Comment: @linuxrocks: the other question is also about assignment which is done in a click-event of a button, so the GUI thread. He also mentioned that he needed to lock this `bool` in the event handler too. That's why he asks if the lock is necessary at all. So for me that is a duplicate, it's even about the same type(`bool`). Note that you need a `lock` even when you just _access_ something that is protected by a `lock` somewhere else.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov: i don't understand in what way Eric L. says something else than Marc G. Yes, it's an atomic operation to assign a value to a `bool` field. But that doesn't prevent you from compiler "optimizations" that threads  cache the value in their registers, so one thread never sees the updated value. `Volatile` does this as [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1222325/284240) has mentioned.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you check my comments carefully there is no mention of fact that volatile is needed or not needed here, I stated that lock isn't need here because it merely guarantees atomically of assignment which is already atomic.

Comment: @TimSchmelter As for additional considerations regarding volatile it's just not enough information in the given piece of code to make any further conclusions as it's not clear how this variable is used.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov: it also provides a memory barrier to ensure that all threads get the most recent value. So you either have to use a lock or volatile. By the way, meanwhile i have read that E. Lippert discourages from ever using volatile fields. He would use a lock. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/ (_"I discourage you from ever making a volatile field"_)

Comment: @DmytroMukalov: sure, maybe he can remove the lock and volatile without any problems. But since this is old code there might be a reason and i wouldnt say it's safe to remove

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know what it does, but again we don't know if a code which verifies the variable can be wrapped with lock so only thing can be clearly stated here that lock ins't needed at that place but volatile may be needed may be not needed.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov: _"but volatile may be needed may be not needed"_ If you've read my comment about E. Lipperts opinion you wouldn't have made this conclusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179110/discussion-between-dmytro-mukalov-and-tim-schmelter).