# C# thread does not set variable value of another class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

here is my testing code:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(delegate() { runThread(); }).Start();

        Console.WriteLine(Global.test);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void runThread()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is run thread");
        Global.test = "this is test from thread";

        Console.WriteLine(Global.test);
    }
}
public class Global
{

    public static string testV { get; set; }
}
```

I want to  be able to set "testV" value with a thread. 
it looks like Thread does set value, but when retrieving testV value from main method, it gives nothing.
why is that?

Comment: The reading from the main thread probably occurs before the other thread had a chance to write the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee that that `Global.test` has been set by the time your main thread calls `WriteLine`.  To see the effects, you could try sleeping for a little bit before writing it out, to prove the other thread has modified it.

Also, it's worth noting that the global static `testV` is not thread-safe and so undefined behaviour is in your future.

Comment: @user1225072, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434890/is-a-string-property-itself-threadsafe

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case `Console.WriteLine(Global.test);` runs earlier, than `runThread`. The simplest way is to use `Join`:

```
var thread = new Thread(delegate() { runThread(); }).Start();
thread.Join();

Console.WriteLine(Global.test);
```

But this is not for production code, definitely (then same is true for manual thread creation too).